# Base de dados crescendo demais - Firebird

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, firebird-2.5

boa tarde.

Usamos o banco de dados Firebird na versão 2.5.9 (SuperClassic) e um dos nossos clientes, que foi implantado recentemente, está crescendo cerca de 1GB por dia a base.

Já rodamos um comando para analisar o tamanho de cada tabela e não chega nem a 20% do tamanho que a base está atualmente:

```sql
/* first update the statistics * /
Update RDB$INDICES SET RDB$STATICS = -1;


/* Display table names and record counts */
SELECT RDB$RELATIONS.RDB$RELATION_NAME,
CASE
WHEN RDB$INDICES.RDB$STATISTICS = 0 THEN 0
ELSE CAST(1 / RDB$INDICES.RDB$STATISTICS AS INTEGER)
END
FROM RDB$RELATIONS
LEFT JOIN RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS
ON RDB$RELATIONS.RDB$RELATION_NAME = RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS.RDB$RELATION_NAME
AND RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
LEFT JOIN RDB$INDICES
ON RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS.RDB$INDEX_NAME = RDB$INDICES.RDB$INDEX_NAME
WHERE RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL AND RDB$RELATION_ID >= 128
ORDER BY 1;
```

Também pensamos que fosse algo no bloco do disco e não é. Acreditamos ser algo relacionado as tabelas de sistema do próprio Firebird, porém, não conseguimos descobrir nada ainda.

Alguém já enfrentou um problema parecido e se sim, como foi solucionado?

Obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, tenta rodar um gbak -b -v -se service_mgr "caminho_da_base" e depois gbak -r -v -se service_mgr  "caminho_da_base"a base deve deminuir o tamanho.
Aparentemente é lixo que fica nas tabelas de sistemas.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AndersonSilva, iniciei os testes aqui. Assim que concluir posto se foi solucionado. Obrigado.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Realizei o bkp/rst com os parâmetros mencionados mas o tamanho permaneceu praticamente o mesmo. Não diminuiu nem 1GB. Estou testando com outros parâmetros e qualquer novidade posto.